# How to deploy servlets to a share Tomcat instance?

Tags: deployment, tomcat, servlets

I've created a servlet app using Netbeans and it works on my local machine.  Now I need to deploy the app to my college class Tomcat 6 instance.  The instance is set up like so: `/java/tomcat/webapps/<student_id>`, where `student_id` are the 30 student IDs for my class.

What exactly do I need to deploy to `/java/tomcat/webapps/elvin` in order to get my servlets to work?  I don't have root access to this machine and I can only write to `/java/tomcat/webapps/elvin`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to let Netbeans create/build a WAR file (there should be one in project's `/dist` folder) and then extract it locally using some ZIP tool and finally copy the extracted contents unchanged into `/webapps/elvin`.

Several things to check:

- Servlet classes should go in a package. Packageless servlets will fail in certain configurations. Java classes should go in a package anyway.
- The Servlet version as declared in `web.xml` must be supported by Tomcat version in question.

  - Tomcat 7.0 supports max Servlet 3.0
  - Tomcat 6.0 supports max Servlet 2.5
  - Tomcat 5.5 supports max Servlet 2.4
  - Tomcat 5.0 supports max Servlet 2.3.

Comment: I did exactly that yet the servlet that's called from my index.jsp can't be found.

Comment: Is the servlet class placed in `WEB-INF/classes/com/example/Servlet.class`? Is the package structure correct? Is the servlet mapped in `web.xml`? Do you have access to Tomcat startup/deploy logs?

Comment: Yes, the classes are under the proper path under WEB-INF.  The servlet is mapped in web.xml.  I used the same web.xml that worked on my local machine.

Comment: How about the logs? Servlets are in a package, right? Which Tomcat version is it? Which Servlet version is declared in `<web-app>` of `web.xml`?

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem.  I was deploying into /webapps/elvin/project1.  So the WEB-INF was under project1.  Once I moved WEB-INF up one directory to /webapps/elvin/WEB-INF, the servlet was executed correctly.  Thanks.